# ET http://127.0.0.1:800/data_list?%20data=hj 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am working with live search in laravel and I am using Ajax and jQuery but my code is not working showing this error

> ET http://127.0.0.1:800/data_list?%20data=hj 500 (Internal Server Error)

This the bootstrap of my code

```
   <div class="card col-lg-9">
    <div class="card-title mt-3">
        <div class="align-lift"><h4>Solar & Power Energy <span class="pull- 
          right">Total Row:</span><span
                        id="tootal_record"></span></h4></div>
        <div align="right">
            <input class="form-control col-lg-4 pull-right" id="search" 
                   name="search" placeholder="search"
                   type="text">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">

        <div class="table table-responsive">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-active">
                <thead class="shadow bg-yellow text-white ">
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Text</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Video</th>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="bg-white">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javaScript code

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            fetch_customer_data();

            function fetch_customer_data(query) {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('spes_data_list') }}",
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        ' data': query
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
                        $('#tootal_record').text(data.total_data);
                    }
                })
            }

            $('#search').on( 'keyup',function () {
                var query = $(this).val();
                fetch_customer_data(query);
                console.log(query);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the laravel code

```
class ServicesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function data_spes_list_from_database(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $query = $request->get('data');

            if (!empty($query )) {
                $data = DB::table('services')->where('title', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('photo', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('vide', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%' . $query . '%')
                        ->get();
            } else {
                $data = DB::table('services')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
            }

            $total_row = $data->count();

            if ($total_row > 0) {
                foreach ($data as $row) {
                    $output = '
              <tr>
              <td>' . $row->id . '</td>
              <td>' . $row->title . '</td>
              <td>' . $row->text . '</td>
              <td>' . $row->created_at . '</td>
              <td>' . $row->video . '</td>
              <td><img style="width:100px;height:100px;" class="" src="' .
```

url('img/user_img/' . $row->photo) . '">

```
              </tr>
              ';
            }

        } else {
            $output = '
            <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="5" >No Data Found </td>
            ';
        }
        $data = array(
            'table_data' => $output,
            'total_data' => $total_row
        );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

This is the web.php route

```
   Route::get('/data_list',
  'admin\ServicesController@data_spes_list_from_database') 
     ->name('spes_data_list');
   Route::post('/edit_list','admin\ServicesController@editSpesList')- 
   >name('spes_edit_list');
```

Comment: Please help me any one

Comment: what is your log says about the error??

Comment: show the following error in GET http://127.0.0.1:800/data_list?%20data=KJ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 error can causes from various reasons. check your `storage/log/todayslog` file to check what causes the error. and as this an ajax request check your browser developer consoles network tab to see what actually going on.

Comment: Make sure the .env file has `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: the browser developer network tab show this one  name:data_list?%20data=j Status:500 type: xhr

Comment: it should give you the details of error

Comment: Thanks, I solved this error the error with database